# mysqli_num_rows keeps returning 1 while 0 should be the answer PHP

Tags: php

So, my problem is that whenever I use this code:

```
$rnumber_query = "SELECT r_number FROM users WHERE user_id='$user'";
$rnumber_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $rnumber_query);
$rnumber_query_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rnumber_query_run);
```

It returns 1 row. This is not correct because there is no data in the table.

I'm trying to use this piece of code to check if a string of numbers exist in the database.

So, that would be:

```
if($rnumber_query_rows == 0) { echo "String does not exist"; } 
else { echo "String does exist!"; }
```

If I run `echo $rnumber_query_rows;` it returns `1` while it should be `0`

---

### UPDATE

Whenever I use the following code it works, but the `mysqli_num_rows` still returns 1.

```
$profile_info_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$profile_info_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $profile_info_query);
$profile_info_row = mysqli_fetch_array($profile_info_query_run, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$rnumber = $profile_info_row['r_number'];

if($rnumber == "") { echo "Works!"; } else { echo "Does not work"; }
```

Output: `Works!`

Comment: Are you sure your users table is empty ?

Comment: If you can not figure out why this is happening, just fetch the rows using mysqli_fetch_array (for testing purpose). This may give you an idea why it returns a wrong answer.

Comment: It's empty. @anantkumarsingh

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help @TismonVarghese

Comment: Your updated script doesn't properly test whether a record has been fetched or not. E.g. the field r_number of the record that has been fetched could just be empty. Better test `if(!$profile_info_row) { echo 'no record'; }`

Comment: Ok. I guess you need to check your database connection. Make sure that it is connected to the same database you are checking. This can happen if we have to work both in server as well as local.

Comment: The connection is fine @TismonVarghese. I've been using that same connection on other pages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (temporary?)

This fixed my issue (for now).

I'm not 100% sure that this will be my final solution as it is not the best way to do it.

Using `if($rnumber == "") { echo "Works!"; } else { echo "Does not work"; }` does work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    die('connect '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
setup($con);

$rnumber_query = "SELECT r_number FROM sofoo_users WHERE user_id='1'";
$rnumber_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $rnumber_query) or die($mysqli->error);
$rnumber_query_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rnumber_query_run);
echo '#=', $rnumber_query_rows;

function setup($mysqli) {
    $mysqli->query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sofoo_users (
            user_id int,
            r_number int
        )
    ');
}
```

prints `#=0` as expected.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I cannot think of anything that could be modifying the information